# Увеличение переменной с помощью 3 потоков, которые переключаются по очереди

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне нужно перебрать int от 0 до 100 с 3 потоками. Так чтобы переменная передавалась из потока в поток. Я сделал так, чтобы было всего 2 потока Consumer и Producer. Но нужно чтобы каждый из трех потоков был и Consumer и Producer одновременно и передавать переменную по кругу пока int не станет 100.

A -> i++ -> send B -> B accepts -> i++ -> send C -> C accepts -> i++ -> send A -> A accepts -> i++

Заранее спасибо за вашу поддержку!

```
public class TransferQueueExample {

TransferQueue<String> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<String>();

class Producer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
            try{
                System.out.println("Producer waiting to transfer: " + i);
                queue.transfer("" + i);
                System.out.println("Producer transferred: " + i);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
            try{
                System.out.println("Consumer waiting to consume: " + i);
                queue.take();
                System.out.println("Consumer consumed: " + i);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    TransferQueueExample example = new TransferQueueExample();
    new Thread(example.new Producer()).start();
    new Thread(example.new Consumer()).start();
}

}
```

Comment: А какой толк тогда от многопоточности? Или это учебное задание?

Comment: примитивные типы нельзя просто так передавать. Они могут разделяться между потоками только если разделяется поле некоторого объекта или класса (статическое поле). В Вашем коде каждый цикл работает со своим локальным `i`. Для начала надо реализовать разделение `i` между двумя потоками. Чтобы понять саму концепцию.

Comment: @Miron да, учебное

Comment: @AlexeyR. тут больше про то чтобы переключаться с одного потока на другой и так по кругу.
Возможно можно взять AtomicInteger, но икрементация думаю идет в довесок просто

Comment: Обязательно чтобы каждый из трёх потоков участвовал в каждом из трех инкрементов? или можно чтобы поток 1 увеличил, потом поток два, потом снова поток 1 потом поток 3?

Comment: @AlexeyR. надо чтобы участвовали все потоки, по очереди
A -> i++ -> send B -> B accepts -> i++ -> send C -> C accepts -> i++ -> send A -> A accepts -> i++

Comment: @AlexeyR. после передачи управления потоку он добавляет +1 и отправляет в следующий поток и так по кругу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Создаем класс объект которого будем шарить:

```java
public class SharedState{

    volatile int i = 0;
    boolean stop = false;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SharedState{" +
                "i=" + i +
                ", stop=" + stop +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2. Создаем класс потока. В этот поток будет входить одна очередь, а исходить из него другая:

```java
public class Incrementer implements Runnable{

    BlockingQueue<SharedState> incomingQueue;
    BlockingQueue<SharedState> outcomingQueue;

    public Incrementer(BlockingQueue<SharedState> incomingQueue,
                       BlockingQueue<SharedState> outcomingQueue){
        this.incomingQueue = incomingQueue;
        this.outcomingQueue = outcomingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                SharedState state = incomingQueue.take();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " took " + state);
                if(state.stop){
                    outcomingQueue.put(state);
                    break;
                }else if (state.i != 100){
                    state.i++;

                }else{
                    state.stop = true;
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sent " + state);
                outcomingQueue.put(state);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

3. Запускаем всё, связывая потоки очередями заколльзованно:

```java
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Main().starter();
    }

    public void starter() throws InterruptedException {
        SharedState sharedState = new SharedState();
        BlockingQueue<SharedState> t1t2 = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
        BlockingQueue<SharedState> t2t3 = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
        BlockingQueue<SharedState> t3t1 = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
        t1t2.put(sharedState);
        new Thread(new Incrementer(t3t1, t1t2)).start();
        new Thread(new Incrementer(t1t2, t2t3)).start();
        new Thread(new Incrementer(t2t3, t3t1)).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Да, я думал также сделать в плане логики но не мог реализовать! Спасибо большое!